# Designing MOSFET bridge rectifiers for high voltages

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, efficiency, bridge-rectifier, powermosfet

I've been looking into MOSFET bridge rectifiers, also known as "zero IQ" rectifiers, as a replacement for traditional diode-based bridge rectifiers.

Here's a simple example:

[image: MOSFET bridge circuit diagram]

The benefit, of course, is that the MOSFETs don't exhibit a forward voltage drop like a regular diode does, allowing for significantly higher efficiency in cases where the current is high or the voltage is low.

The major limiting factor for higher power designs seems to be that you can't get MOSFETs with a V<sub>gs(max)</sub> high enough to rectify voltages exceeding 80V or so. There are some control ICs that are designed to help with higher voltage rectification (e.g. [LT4320](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt4320.html), [LM74670](http://www.ti.com/product/LM74670-Q1)) but they too are limited to around 75V continuous.

My first thought to solve this issue was to clamp the voltage with zeners, but I ran into the issue that you can clamp the voltage on two of the transistors just fine, but when you try to do all four you just get shoot-through because the diodes provide a path directly across the AC input.

I also thought about using IGBTs instead, but they appear to also have fairly limited gate voltages.

Is there a way to solve this issue, either by designing around the gate voltage limit somehow, or by changing the topology?

Comment: You need isolated gate drivers and I don't think you can control them off the line. You need a controller. This all makes it significantly more complicated than what you seem to have in mind. Complicated enough that you would just go with all NMOS because PMOS isn't saving any circuitry.

Comment: Could you put together an answer that explains how that would work? I'm trying to think of how the individual gate drive voltages would be created without negating the efficiency gains over a regular bridge (at, say, 30A/200V), but I can't quite get it together in my mind. I don't mind putting together a more complex design, if mostly only out of academic curiosity rather than practicality.

Comment: The transistors basically get controlled individually as if they were the high side transisors in an inverter or motor driver. Look that up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following there. I thought an inverter was a circuit that took a DC power input and generated an AC power output? Or do you mean like an inverter logic gate?

Comment: Inverters can be programmed turn transistors on and off differently to do many things.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucqGR.jpg Doesn't the rectifier part look vaguely like the inverter part? This is three phase but it's the same with H-bridges and bridge rectifiers.

Comment: Sure, I guess? But I'm not sure that really helps me here, since the switching is all being done on the low voltage side before being boosted by the output transformer.

Comment: The point is that an inverter is just a rectifier with transistors instead of diodes and nothing is stopping you from sending current in the opposite direction through it and making it switch however you need. Which is what you have right now sans the support and control circuits.

Comment: One of the features of a rectifier bridge is that the smoothing cap doesn't discharge back into mains when mains voltage is lower than the DC on the cap... so what if the output of this rectifier is connected to a big smoothing cap?

Comment: It shorts the output since it conducts a full half cycle instead of a 1/4 cycle max.  The charge cycle must always be 50% max and drops to % Vdc ripple

Comment: @Dave Tweed Your deleted cct with diode deeding the 10ks should work. FETS then only conduct when AC is "above" the output voltage .

Comment: _"I also thought about using IGBTs instead"_ - but they have relatively high voltage drop and so don't solve the original problem.

Comment: is this https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ7270DI.pdf of interest?

Comment: @onepound Looks good. $US2 in 100's [from LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/search?q=AOZ7270DI)  - and $3.35 [from Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/alpha-omega-semiconductor-inc/AOZ7270DI/14682851?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIIHkBaB2MKAMARAkiAugL5A) in 1000's.

Comment: @onepound Nice! Looks like they have a whole brand new line of HV AC/DC bridge rectifiers based on this tech.

Comment: I am slightly surprised that the performance graphs show it beating diodes though, given the fairly high 190mΩ Rds(on). Although that is specified as the maximum, so maybe it has a much lower Rds(on) during the majority of the cycle.

Comment: [AOZ7271DV](https://aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/datasheets/AOZ7271DV.pdf) is a newer part from the same series with lower Rds(on).

Comment: A07Z271V  -  125 milliohm.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes, that's the part I just linked.

Comment: @Polynomial Yes. I got the value from your link. I thought it worth noting what the new Rdson values were. || Very strangely, the current capability is not mentioned anywhere in the  data sheet. || The older part [AOZ7270DI](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ7270DI.pdf)  is rated at 20 A max continuous at 25C and 12A at 100 C. At 10A Pd ~= 12 Watt/device. Vf = 1.25V. || The best [equivalent Schottky diodes](https://www.digikey.co.nz/short/8j57473b) are about the same voltage drop at twice that current - but cost more. ||

Comment: Nice Schottky   600V, 34A continuous at 125C. 300 uA reverse leakage at 175C at 650 V reverse voltage. https://assets.wolfspeed.com/uploads/2023/05/Wolfspeed_C6D20065H_data_sheet.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rectifier may not work as you expect or need.

The MOSFETs will turn on and conduct for the appropriate leg of the circuit, but unlike a conventional rectifier, they will remain conducting on the 'trailing' edge of the AC input. Thus if you want to peak-rectify the signal, it won't work -- the FETs will discharge the capacitor also.

You can add a diode (or even a Schottky) at the output; or you can replace 2 of the MOSFETs with simple diodes. That way, the whole bridge rectifier will only have a drop of one diode + FET resistance, not 2 diodes as a conventional rectifier.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Dave Tweed noted that this circuit has issues.
I'll leave it here as it helps inform the problem.
See comments.

This is based on Dave Tweed's now deleted circuit with 4 added diodes.

The diodes in series with the 10k resistors drive the FETs on only when Vmains is above V_DC_out for a given FET by Vf_diode + Vth_FET.

[image]

Diagram is a hacked about cut and paste version of Dave Tweed's diagram.

Dave Tweed said:

If you use, say, 10 V 400 mW zeners, they can handle an average current of 40 mA. 10k resistors let you handle around 400 V.

But pay attention to the power dissipation in the resistors, too. Larger values of resistance will dissipate less power, but they'll also slow down the switching somewhat.

Comment: This doesn't work. The additional diodes prevent the MOSFETs from ever turning on.

Comment: @DaveTweed Whoops - true. Rotate the diodes 180 degrees. Silly me. You get the point though. With diodes of correct polarity I think it works. Yes?

Comment: No. Then you still have Tony's problem of shoot-through whenever the voltage is high enough to turn all of the transistors on at once. This "trick" only works for low-voltage applications, where it has the most value. High-voltage applications need a much more complex control circuit. That's why I gave up and deleted my answer.